# Why does locate */file*name work, and locate file*name does not?

Tags: locate

The following is working as inteded:

```
$ locate */synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy 
/mnt/home/dario/temp/synse_resources/language_modelling/repo_test_cadavae_5_r_val/bert/cadavae_5_r_unseen_zs.npy                                                                                                   /mnt/home/dario/temp/synse_resources/language_modelling/repo_test_synse_10_r_val/bert/synse_10_r_unseen_zs.npy
```

```
$ locate synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy
```

This however, return nothing.

What's up?

EDIT: Debugging:

```
$ echo */synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy 
*/synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy
$ echo /synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy
/synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy
$ echo synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy
synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy
```

Comment: What do `echo */synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy ` and `echo /synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` 
output?

Comment: @muru , nothing illuminating

Comment: is the database up to date?

Comment: Note that you should really wrap these arguments with single quotes to stop the shell from interpreting the asterisk before passing along the arguments to the `locate` command. For example, do this: `locate 'foo*bar'`, not this: `locate foo*bar`

Comment: I'm not at a terminal right now, but I've seen similar before, the /filename might be searching for that file with an asterisk as part of the name (ie verbatim), or that file only in the root dir, but the * at the beginning tells it to use wildcard mode, try specifying the mode; or remove the preceding /.

Answer (score 3):

When locating files a locate command that contains standard wildcards (also known as globbing patterns) is looking for paths to files in its local database. `/synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` is not a complete path to a file, so `locate /synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` returns nothing (because the search results of `locate synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` in your Ubuntu are an empty set), however `*/synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` is a complete path to file(s), so `locate */synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` returns the results of the command. The asterisk character in these commands is interpreted by locate as a wildcard. The asterisk can represent any number of characters (including zero, in other words, zero or more characters).

Comment: It might also be worth noting that if the string doesn't contain *any* wildcard characters, then `locate` implicitly adds a leading and trailing `*`

Comment: Txs so much for your answer, but I had an important typo in my question. The bafflingness I would like explained is why `locate synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

As @steeldriver mentioned, `locate` by default attaches a `*` wildcard to the beginning and end of the search term (so `locate abc` is actually `locate *abc*`) *except* when you add a wild card yourself to the search term, then it does not append nor prepend the extra `*` wild cards.

So, while `$ locate synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` finds nothing because it's not prepending a `*` to the search term, `$ locate *synse_*_r_unseen_zs.npy` finds the expected

```
/mnt/home/dario/temp/synse_resources/language_modelling/repo_test_cadavae_5_r_val/bert/cadavae_5_r_unseen_zs.npy                                                                                                   /mnt/home/dario/temp/synse_resources/language_modelling/repo_test_synse_10_r_val/bert/synse_10_r_unseen_zs.npy
```